# How to read Regex from URL

Tags: regex

I'm beginner with regex, and not able to figure out how to capture variable while writing url structure.

```
.*://[a-z\-.]+/([\w-]*)

http://localhost/anything-here-goes-comes-here-p90
http://best-discount-deals.com/anything-here-goes-comes-here-c90
http://www.gadgetbroadway.com/anything-here-goes-comes-here-p90
```

I'm currently stuck with above regex, which is able to parse the slug but don't know how to capture last part of slug (p90 or c90), the rule "\s\d{1,8}" for last segment.

If I use regex than .*://[a-z-.]+/([\w-]*) not able to capture the last part as it will automatically covered by ([\w-]*) group.

Any thoughts guys?

Comment: Just append [`-(\S\d{1,8})$`](http://rubular.com/r/W9JvqfMFAL)?

Comment: still i'm not able to capture char ahead of id i.e. c or p

Comment: You want to capture that separately or?

Comment: yes capture char and number both separately as group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the end:

```
-([^-]+)$
```

Comment: A bit harsh with the downvoting.  Granted it doesn't enforce his intended rule, but it still captures the group and is simpler, which I'm not going to assume is unacceptable.

Comment: It is surely working, I'm able to capture the last part of slug thanks.

Comment: I wasn't sure why the first suggestion, -(\S\d{1,8})$ didn't work, however.  I can only imagine a complication with the putting backslashes in front of the parentheses and braces.  But you said it matched the numbers, so I'm not sure what's going on.  That's why I suggested the simpler route.